# Input string was not in a correct format ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have a expression for column group(on matrix report, which shows report of 12 months)

```
=iif(Fields!CR_MONTH.Value ="","0",Fields!CR_MONTH.Value)
```

but I got error message as

> The Group expression for the grouping 'Months' contains error: Input
>   string was not in a correct format.

How to get rid of errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below and don't forget to do the same changes in Sorting tab of the group.

Assuming your Fields!CR_MONTH.Value is an integer field.

```
=iif(ISNOTHING(Fields!CR_MONTH.Value),0,Fields!CR_MONTH.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the CR_MONTH an Int or a string? if it is an integer, then change your grouping expression to have the middle value as an integer as well:

```
=iif(Fields!CR_MONTH.Value ="",0,Fields!CR_MONTH.Value)
```